# Can I find a value that absolutely increase from a linux os?

Tags: linux, timestamp

I know it's strange, but it will helpful.
I found two ways:

1. UNIX timestamp, it can keep absolute increment unless the datetime of the system(linux) is not modified unexpectedly.
2. Maintain a value manually such as in file/sqlite/mysql. But it difficult to do this in my situation.

Is there some value or some method in linux os?

Comment: Please modify your question so the community can understand it better. Are you saying you have tried those two approaches but were not helpful? For #1, do you mean "unless the datetime **is not modified** unexpectedly"?

Comment: Thanks. The two approaches I tried have some flaw. In first approach, the system datetime may be modified by somebody. Second, in my situation I can not maintain the absolutely increased value manually. I just want get the existing value that increased by linux system.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I discussed this issue with my friend. They think it maybe a philosophical problem:)